# How do I use configuration variables in Tesseract?

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, tesseract

I went through this tutorial successfully: [Tesseract OCR Tutorial for iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2010498-tesseract-ocr-tutorial-for-ios). It uses the [Tesseract OCR iOS framework](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS).

The app works well with the sample image provided by the tutorial, but none of my own images that I test work (the output is gibberish).

To troubleshoot, the docs recommend [toggling a configuration variable](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#image-processing) `tessedit_write_images` to `true` (or using configfile `get.images`) to view the image file to be processed. But I don't see where to set the boolean value and I'm not sure where to place or how to use a configfile.

Search for "tessedit_write_images" in the files in Xcode don't return anything.

Comment: Not an answer: I recommend using Apple's [Vision framework](https://bendodson.com/weblog/2019/06/11/detecting-text-with-vnrecognizetextrequest-in-ios-13/) instead. I've gone through tesseract and the other options and none of them were as fast or accurate as Vision. Vision was also way easier to use.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion in the past few hours!

Answer (score 3):

You can set configuration variables either by providing as command line option or in a configuration file

**Using Command Line Option**

```
$tesseract input.jpg output.txt --oem 2 -l eng -c tessedit_write_images=1

   -c configvar=value
       Set value for control parameter. Multiple -c arguments are allowed.
```

**Using Config File (myConfig) Option**

```
$ tesseract Lord_Saraswathi.jpg text --oem 2 -l eng myConfig

$ cat myConfig
```

tessedit_write_images 1